# How long should I cook boned shoulder of Lamb?

Tags: roast, lamb

I have 794g of lamb shoulder. It is boned (can you buy it with a bone in??). How long should I cook it?

I have *Delia's Complete Cooking Course*, which suggests cooking for 30 minutes at 230C plus 30 degrees at 180C per pound (450G); about 1hr 20 minutes.

[Delia Online](http://www.deliaonline.com/how-to-cook/meat/roasting-times.html) just says 30 minutes per pound at 190C.

Which would people recommend?

Comment: Usually, unless you're slow cooking it, the best way to cook meat is with a thermometer. Do you have one?

Comment: Unfortunately not; I've gone with 52 minutes at 190C... We'll see how it turns out!

Answer (score 6):

Shoulder is a tough cut. I think you will probably find it a bit chewy if you've cooked it at 190ºC for 52 minutes. In future, preheat the oven to maximum, place the lamb in a roasting tin, cover the tin with foil, put the tin in the oven, then immediately turn the oven down to 150ºC, and leave it for 4 hours. After that time, take it out of the oven and let it rest for 30 minutes or so. The lamb will melt in your mouth.

And yes, you can buy a bone-in shoulder at just about any supermarket, and they are usually tastier. Cook it as above and you will just be able to pull the bone out of the meat.

Comment: 150ºC is a bit too low and slow for modern lamb, as it has so much fat trimmed off. Try around 160ºC at 1.5 to 2 hours per kg. Either way make sure you baste the surface with the drippings regularly. Go with the bone in too! See http://www.beeflambnz.co.nz/

Comment: No it isn't, I do it all the time. New Zealand lamb may have the fat trimmed off, but here in the UK shoulder is still a fatty cut. If you cover the pan with foil you don't need to baste as it prevents the surface from drying out too much.

Comment: I'd also recommend a marinade and a short spell of grilling in some rosemary, garlic and honey for example. Golden brown on the outside, slow cooked gorgeous on the inside :). I've also tried 6-8 hours of 120 degrees on a barbecue. I think the slower, the better.

Comment: The high heat blast at the beginning performs the same task as grilling would, but grilling would impart a great flavour. I would put it in the oven at 150 rather than doing the whole high heat/turn down thing.

Answer (score 0):

If boned ensure the joint is tied tightly with cooking twine, trim the fat so that it is uniform all around and lightly score. Brown all external surfaces on a hot pan/skillet. Remove and season as desired. Place on a rack in a roasting tray in 160c preheated oven for 2-3 hours, basting occassionally. Check internal temperature of joint, 60c is juicy! Remove and rest for 20 mins before carving.